# The best way to classify vector images from photos?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, classification

I need to separate images into three categories: vectors, photos with vectors and pure photos. The classifying needs to happen in "real-time" so this leads me to my question: **what would be good algorithm for classifying these types of images from accuracy/performance tradeoff perspective?**

Images are not my speciality so all pointers are appreciated.

For performance heavy side of things I tried tensorflow with inception to get a baseline however the model reached only ~88% accuracy. I conclude this is due Inception being a photo classifying model and something like a solid color vector doesn't really fit into its world.

There must be easier/more lightweight solution than deep learning to detect such a different type of images?

**EXAMPLES:**

Photo:

[image]

Photo with vector:

[image]

Vector:

[image]

Comment: Do you have examples of each?

Comment: Yes. I've about ~10000 test set of each type.

Comment: I meant for you to post some, so we can see what you mean.

Comment: Ah, sorry, of course. Added examples.

Comment: 88% is already quite good, it will increase with more data, you could try other networks.

Comment: I don't know quite how to express what I'm after because like I said, images are not my speciality, but what are more lightweight solutions I could try? Other than other ANNs. Personally I would go for a good TF model but I'm not sure whether it's realistic possibility here due the performance requirements.